# How to convert string of a bytestring to bytestring?

Tags: python, string, hex, byte

I've pulled some data from SQL database and one of the columns is UUIDs of bytes type. I should've hexed it, but I was in a hurry and I just dumped everything into csv as is. Now when I read that csv with pandas, the IDs column is a string of a bytestring (if that make sense).

What I need `b'>\xc8\xb4hq\x14K\xb7\xad\xb0\x9e\xda\x86Q\xfaV'` 
What I actually have `"b'>\xc8\xb4hq\x14K\xb7\xad\xb0\x9e\xda\x86Q\xfaV'"` 
What Python shows `"b'>\\xc8\\xb4hq\\x14K\\xb7\\xad\\xb0\\x9e\\xda\\x86Q\\xfaV'"` 
If I try to encode what I have `b"b'>\\xc8\\xb4hq\\x14K\\xb7\\xad\\xb0\\x9e\\xda\\x86Q\\xfaV'"`

Tried reading the file differently, setting different dtypes, encoding, decoding, converting back and forth with no success. 
When I was dumping data into csv, I received an escapechar error. After quick glance on the internet, I've added `dump_frame.to_csv(..., escapechar='\\')` parameter without giving much of a thought. Not sure if this has do to with anything.

I will eventually need a hexed value
`b'>\xc8\xb4hq\x14K\xb7\xad\xb0\x9e\xda\x86Q\xfaV'.hex() == '3ec8b46871144bb7adb09eda8651fa56'`, but I cannot do it 6 million times by hand.

I did find an ugly workaround with `eval`, which takes exactly what I have and returns exactly what I need. I could append results to a list and loop over all IDs that I have. But I refuse to believe this is the best way of doing it.

```
test_id = "b'>\\xc8\\xb4hq\\x14K\\xb7\\xad\\xb0\\x9e\\xda\\x86Q\\xfaV'"
eval(test_id + ".hex()")
```

I could query the database again (hexing IDs at the server side this time), but I want a solution with a Python to this debacle. I feel I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert the representation of a literal to its value.

Comment: So, I can just `ast.literal_eval(test_id).hex()`. This is something I didn't know. Thanks.